# Loading a raster in r

Tags: r, raster

I am trying to make a sampling design in R and I have a Sentinel 2 raster I want to use. I am using the `mygrd` to set in and I cant get it to load? It gives me a "Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U" message and i dont know what I am doing wrong?
I am trying to use the sentinel 2 image as my shape of the sampling points. I have tried other methods as `setwd`.

[image]

Comment: you should include code and messages, but do use screenshots, that is very inconvenient. Also I answered the question before you added this, but the answer is still correct, why don't you acknowledge that?

Answer (score 0):

Path names in R use forward slashes. So it should be something like `"c:/User/Derrick/mygrd.tif"`